# The 'e' parameter in function's prototype method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, parameters, event-bubbling

I want use e parameter to stop javascript bubble

here is my code:

```
function test(){}
test.prototype.method=function(parameter,e){
    console.log(parameter)
    e.preventDefault();
}
var t=new test();

$(function(){
    $('.node').click(function(){
       t.method($(this).attr('id'),e);
    });
});
```

however,it doesn't work,the firebug tell me the "e is not defined"

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why not simply `return false;`? Usually it has the same effect..

Comment: @ShadowWizard:no,I tryed it,only I use e.stopPropagation(),this could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the call site

```
t.method($(this).attr('id'),e);
```

there is no symbol named `e` in scope; therefore, the browser complains. Since symbols do not magically appear, you want to tell the browser that `e` is the first argument passed in your `click` handler:

```
$('.node').click(function(e){ // ADDED FORMAL PARAMETER
   t.method($(this).attr('id'),e);
});
```

You know that there *will* be a parameter passed to the handler because the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) say that your `handler` will be given an `eventObject` -- but of course you are free to name the parameter as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
$(function(){
    $('.node').click(function(){
       t.method($(this).attr('id'),e);
    });
});
```

To this (you forgot to put the e in your function)

```
$(function(){
    $('.node').click(function(e){
       t.method($(this).attr('id'),e);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Made it a bit prettier.

Using `$(this).attr('id')` is a waste of resources by the way. You can simply get the id like I did in the code belove.

```
$(function(){
    $('.node').on('click',function(e) {
       t.method(this.id,e);
    });
});
```

In your `method` you should expand your code with the following:

```
if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
else
    e.stop();
```